# How to compare one value in a row to see if it is higher than 75% of all values in the same column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, comparison

I have a table that looks like this:

```
groups  created_utc            score    count_comments  d_posts ups  downs   ratio
group1  2011-07-11T19:05:19Z    6988    3742             56     8530  1572   .42(8530/20286)
group2  2011-04-23T21:29:12Z    10455   4695             512    11756 1303   .58(11756/20286)
```

Generated from this query:

```
SELECT *, ups  / SUM(ups) OVER () AS ratio
FROM table
order by ratio desc;
```

How do I compare each value in `ratio` column by row to see if that ratio is greater than 75% of all the ratios to create a new flag column, `greater_75p`?

The new table should look like this (cant get the new col formatted but should be `y/n` as options):

```
groups  created_utc            score    count_comments  d_posts ups  downs   ratio                greater_75p
                                                                                                   y 
group1  2011-07-11T19:05:19Z    6988    3742             56     8530  1572   .42(8530/20286)
group2  2011-04-23T21:29:12Z    10455   4695             512    11756 1303   .58(11756/20286)
```

I tried this query, but get error `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`:

```
SELECT *,ups * 100 / SUM(ups) OVER () AS ratio, 
PERCENT_RANK() OVER(order by (SELECT ups * 100 / SUM(ups) OVER () AS ratio from table )) AS greater_75p
FROM table
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong and how to derive a comparison in percentages within sql?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get result of `percent_rank()` you can use common table expression as below:

```
with cte as
(SELECT *, ups  / SUM(ups) OVER () AS ratio
FROM table) 
select *,(case when percent_rank()over(order by ration) >0.75 then 'yes' else 'no' end) greater_75p from cte
```

Please clarify the logic for calculating `greater_75p` column.

Comment: thanks for the response! this looks promising. The logic for the `greater_75p` is that if the ratio is higher than 75% of all other ratios, then add 'y' flag to the new column.

Comment: @RustyShackleford I have revised my answer based on your clarification. Hope it's your desired answer now.

Comment: this is looking good. Out of curiosity do you think quantiles would be a better option? https://hevodata.com/learn/bigquery-quantiles/#6

Comment: I am not sure @RustyShackleford. But I would prefer percent_rank().